# can someone explain the idea of this integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$\int{dx\over x}+ \int {2ue^u-1\over 2u^2e^u+2}du=C$$

$$\int{dx\over x}+{1\over2} \int {d(u^2e^u+1)\over u^2e^u+1}du-{1\over2}\int {du}=C$$

im doing differential equation and try to separate variable, but im stuck at here. can someone explain how to integral this one
$\int {2ue^u-1\over 2u^2e^u+2}du$ ?? whats the idea in the second line?
how to make this $d(u^2e^u+1)$ ?

original question: $(2ye^{y/x}-x)y'+2x+y=0$
doing by substitue $y/x=u$

Comment: Can you pose the original question?

Comment: @crazy $(2ye^{y/x}-x)y'+2x+y=0$ its f(x/y)dx+g(y/x)dy=0

Answer (score 0):

Adding and substracting something well chosen:

$$\int {2ue^u-1\over 2u^2e^u+2}du=$$

$$=\dfrac12 \int {2ue^u+u^2e^u-u^2e^u-1\over u^2e^u+1}du=$$

$$={1\over 2}\int {2ue^u+u^2e^u\over u^2e^u+1}du-{1\over 2}\int {u^2e^u+1\over u^2e^u+1}du=$$

$$={1\over 2}\int {d(u^2e^u+1)\over u^2e^u+1}-{1\over 2}\int du$$

With, $d(u^2e^u+1)=(2ue^u+u^2e^u)du$, using the derivative of the product.

Comment: hello thanks! i got it, but how you now that you must add or substract like that to make it easier to solve? and also im not familiar with this one $={1\over 2}\int {d(u^2e^u+1)\over u^2e^u+1}du$ why there is du here?

Comment: suppose i have $u^2e^u+1=p$ then differentiate $(2ue^u+u^2e^u)=dp/du$ then $={1\over 2}\int {2ue^u+u^2e^u\over u^2e^u+1}du$ will be $={1\over 2}\int {dp\over p}$ so not need du? what is the role of du here?

Comment: You are right, $du$ is not necessary as you incorporate it into the differential as I do in the last line. I fix it now.

Comment: Having the big hint about the result it's easy to see what term you need simply doing the differential. With no hints it's more difficult, I think that as the "add and substact something" is a useful "trick", the numerator is "almost" the  derivative of the denominator and exponential functions (with the same derivative as itself), one have the task to put it all together. There is no a simple algorithm to solve integrals as is to calculate derivatives, as you know...

Comment: Thanks!!! And also i tend to think that i should doing partial differentiation from the first step.. is it possible? Yeah but i realize that derivative is the big hint and sometimes there are many problems that the solution is fix like you have to change it to another formula so you can integrate it